# Unrecognized VM option 'MetaspaceSize=96M & Could not create the Java virtual machine. when trying to run keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to run keycloak locally. I have installed `keycloak-24.0.1` and tried to run `./kc.sh start-dev` but it shows me this current errors :
`Unrecognized VM option 'MetaspaceSize=96M'` and
`Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

I'm using `openjdk version "17.0.10"` and ubuntu as an OS.

Comment: It seemed that my `JAVA_HOME` was pointing on a different java version ( jdk 6 ) which is not compatible with the keycloak version. I simply switched to jdk 8 and it worked.